# Assigning a value to a variable in SQL exec

Tags: sql-server-2005

It's possible to assign a value to a variable returned from `exec @sql`?:

```
set @var= exec calculate 'param' are this true
```

Answer (score 2):

```
DECLARE @ret INT
DECLARE @output INT

EXEC @ret = [proc] @input, @output OUTPUT

SELECT @ret, @output
```

`@ret` is the return value: `RETURN -1`
`@output` is an assignable variable of any type: `SET @output = 123`

Answer (score 0):

You should be using output parameters for the stored procedure:

```
DECLARE @output1 INT
EXEC [proc] @input, @output1 OUTPUT

PRINT @output1
```

Answer (score 0):

A function is a good place to perform a commonly used calculation.

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.ufnAddIntegers
    (@pint1 as int, @pint2 as int)
RETURNS int
AS
BEGIN
   return @pint1 + @pint2
END
go

declare @intResult int
set @intResult = dbo.ufnAddIntegers(3, 4)
select Result = @intResult

/*
Result
-----------
7
*/
```

Comment: thanks @peterellis its good solution.put whats diffrence between 
functions and stored procedure